Server Error: Super expression must either be null or a function while using typewriter-effect
When i using  typewriter-effet it shows problem ,
Server Error: Super expression must either be null or a function
my components ( from documentation:https://www.npmjs.com/package/typewriter-effect )
import React from 'react';
import Typewriter from 'typewriter-effect';

const TypeWriterText = () => {
    return (
        <Typewriter
            options={{
                strings: ['Hello', 'World'],
                autoStart: true,
                loop: true,
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default TypeWriterText;

import React from 'react';
import Typewriter from 'typewriter-effect';

const TypeWriterText = () => {
    return (
        <Typewriter
            options={{
                strings: ['Hello', 'World'],
                autoStart: true,
                loop: true,
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default TypeWriterText;


Does this answer your question? Super expression must either be null or a function nextjs 13
